# Mobile SDK: The REST API is not enabled for this Organization

Tags: connected-apps, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I created a trial account on [Salesforce](https://login.salesforce.com/)

Developed an Android app using Trailhead:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/mobile_sdk_native_android/mobilesdk_android_getting_started

When I try to login using the Email and Password, it logs in fine but the *Fetch Contacts* and *Fetch Accounts* throw this error:

> [{"message":"The REST API is not enabled for this
>   Organization.","errorCode":"API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG"}]

The Developer account I used to create the Connected App, has API Enabled and it works fine with the [Saleforce1 App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.chatter&hl=en).

Somewhere I read:

> To be able to use the Rest APIs we need to login with Username(not
>   Email). Which is not the case with Salesforce1 App. Because most of
>   the Users will not have a Username.
>
> And I don't find a way to add a Username. The link under my profile
>   icon which says **Add Username** keeps asking for login and never
>   actually prompts to create Username.

Comment: What edition did you create for your trial? It has to be enterprise or above to have the API enabled.

Comment: @Eric Where do I check that? I don't remember choosing any such option. 1. Does the API enable issue depend on the Account I created to connect app and get the Customer Key? or the Account I am using to log into the Trailhead app? 2. Like I mentioned in the question - The account I am using to login works fine on Salesforce1 app with both email and username. But on the Trailhead app it doesn't work with email, however it works with Username.

Comment: Setup -> Company Profile -> Company Information -> look for "Organization Edition"

Comment: Professional Edition. How do I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What edition did you create for your trial? It has to be enterprise or above to have the API enabled.

To Check:

Setup -> Company Profile -> Company Information -> look for "Organization Edition"

Since from your comment your are on PE edition, you will need to create a new trial org and ensure you are selecting Enterprise or above

Comment: "you will need to create a new trial org and ensure you are selecting Enterprise" a new signup?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc - yup

Comment: https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp where is the option to choose the edition? I tried from https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/ clicking on **Try For Free** under **Lightning Enterprise**, but it still created a Professional Edition. Also I suppose this is for the account that is going to create the connected app and the customer key right? not the account that tries to use the API.

Comment: If you are developing an application you should probably obtain a Developer Edition from developer.salesforce.com

Comment: That created a Developer Edition. Even now the same issue exists. I could login with **Username and Email both but for Email Fetch Contacts always throw "API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG" error**. It works fine with the Username.

Comment: Is it possible for anyone who has an account on https://www.salesforce.com/ to login using their credentials(email, password) in my app and access the APIs(profile info, contacts etc..)?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc - Are you using oAuth? Is API enable don the users profile? What are the settings of the connected app....There are lots of moving parts and with the information provided it is impossible to pin it down....Suggest you start a new question with specific details on all the moving parts. Make sure to mark this as answered (if you feel it is appropriate to close it out) since the PE edition was your first problem....

Comment: @Archie.bpgc - The connected APP simply defines the access level your app has to their org. The customer can also modify those permission from what you have defined as well

Comment: I just added a new question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159764/developer-edition-the-rest-api-is-not-enabled-for-this-organization will mark this as answered