# Developer Edition: The REST API is not enabled for this Organization

Tags: connected-apps, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I created a developer account [here](https://developer.salesforce.com)

Followed **Creating a Connected App** on https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/mobile_sdk_native_android/units/mobilesdk_android_getting_started

Cross checked if API is enabled from **System Administrator Profile**

[image]

Connected APP Settings:

[image]

Now from the Trailhead app I login with Email and Password of a Trial account(Professional Edition) I created on [Salesforce Dev](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup). It logs in fine but the API calls like Fetch Contacts/Accounts throw:

> [{"message":"The REST API is not enabled for this
>   Organization.","errorCode":"API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG"}]

However those APIs work with a Username and Password.

**Questions:**

1. If I create a Developer account, add a connected app and integrate Salesforce into my Android app will any other User with a Salesforce account(non-developer) be able to login and access the API? Like in the [Salesforce1 Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.chatter)

   2. Username exists only for Developer accounts?

Comment: Per the previous question the connect APP defines the access your app has to the users org. If the user is on PE then your app cannot connect. if you are registered as an ISV you can get an API key so your app will work. Someone here may be able to give you details. If you want to test your app, use a user from an org that is EE or above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API access for professional edition will disabled by default and you will need to contact salesforce to get it enabled .

To request API contact via your partner org

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_api_access.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_faq_request_api_token.htm

You should fine using a developer org .Sign up with a developer org and you can access REST and SOAP API's

Comment: **Sign up with a developer org and you can access REST and SOAP API's** This is for anyone who wants to user Salesforce from my app? Because most likely this will be disabled on User accounts. Salesforce1 Android app doesn't have this restriction?

Comment: Yes the user on the dev org can access rest and API in the dev org. If the user logging in using your connect app credentials it is to that users org and if PE they do not have rest or api enabled so your app cannot access it. Logging in via your app does not log them into the org where your app resides

Comment: 1 thing that confuses is that the same account(Dev Edition) is able to access API when logged in with Username, but not with the Email. What is the difference? Because even if I get an enterprise edition(non-dev) that might have the same issue because there is no Username.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc - You cannot login using an email. You can only login using a username. Usually the username is your email address but it could be a different address. (Unless you are using SSO then I guess a username other than an email address would work)

Comment: @Eric I see. So to sum up using just a Developer account I can connect an app and integrate Salesforce in my android app. To be able to access the APIs depends on the User who logs in? i.e they must be using Dev or Higher than PE right?

Comment: @Archie Yes that's correct